# save query in temporary table in isq

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the query

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt) AS WeekDay,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleCount) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear) as PERCENTILE,
        AVG(SaleCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt), IsPromo) AS AVG_WeekDay
    FROM 
        [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy]
)
UPDATE a 
SET SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
FROM CTE
JOIN [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy] a ON a.Dt = cte.dt
                                        AND a.ItemRelation = cte.ItemRelation 
                                        AND a.DocumentNum = cte.DocumentNum 
                                        AND a.DocumentYear = cte.DocumentYear 
                                        AND a.ispromo = cte.ispromo
WHERE CTE.PERCENTILE < CTE.SaleCount
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CTE.Dt) < 5
  AND CTE.ispromo = 0 ;
```

When I run it, my table promo_data_copy is updated. It is not right.

Tell me, please, how to do, that,  final result will return in the temporary table, let "temp_table"?

**Edit:**

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt) AS WeekDay,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleCount) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear) as PERCENTILE,
        AVG(SaleCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt), IsPromo) AS AVG_WeekDay
    FROM 
        [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy]
)
SELECT * 
INTO #temp_table 
FROM cte 

SET SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
FROM CTE
JOIN #temp_table a ON a.Dt = cte.dt
                   AND a.ItemRelation = cte.ItemRelation 
                   AND a.DocumentNum = cte.DocumentNum 
                   AND a.DocumentYear = cte.DocumentYear 
                   AND a.ispromo = cte.ispromo
WHERE CTE.PERCENTILE < CTE.SaleCount
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CTE.Dt) < 5
  AND CTE.ispromo = 0 ;
```

The error

> Msg 102, level 15, state 1, line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near the "=" construct.

**Edit #2:**

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt) AS WeekDay,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleCount) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear) as PERCENTILE,
        AVG(SaleCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dt), IsPromo) AS AVG_WeekDay
    FROM 
        [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy]
)
SELECT * 
INTO #temp_table 
FROM cte 

UPDATE a
SET SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
FROM #temp_table
JOIN #temp_table a ON a.Dt = cte.dt
                   AND a.ItemRelation = cte.ItemRelation 
                   AND a.DocumentNum = cte.DocumentNum 
                   AND a.DocumentYear = cte.DocumentYear 
                   AND a.ispromo = cte.ispromo
WHERE CTE.PERCENTILE < CTE.SaleCount
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CTE.Dt) < 5
  AND CTE.ispromo = 0 ;
```

Then I get many errors of the same type

> Msg 4104, level 16, state 1, line 11
>   Could not bind composite identifier "cte.dt"
>
> Msg 4104, level 16, state 1, line 11
>   Could not bind composite identifier "cte.ItemRelation"
>
> Msg 4104, level 16, state 1, line 11
>   Could not bind composite identifier "cte.DocumentNum"

How can I correct the query?

Comment: why would you not expect your table `promo_data_copy` to not be updated? YOu have aliased it as `a` and your statement is `UPDATE a`.

Comment: @larnu see please edit of my post

Comment: You have a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, and then start a new statement with `SET`. A `SET` clause needs to be be preceded by `UPDATE [tablename]`. Also, you can't reference the CTE from your previous statement, as it isn't declared. A CTE can only be referenced in the statement it is included in. For example try: `WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 AS one) SELECT * FROM CTE; SELECT * FROM CTE;` Notice the second `SELECT` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding you right you want the CTE to go into the temp table which can be accomplished with:

```
 with cte as (
    Select *,datePart(WEEKDAY,Dt) as WeekDay,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleCount) Over (partition by ItemRelation,
    DocumentNum, DocumentYear) as PERCENTILE,
    avg(SaleCount) over (Partition by ItemRelation, 
    DocumentNum, DocumentYear,datePart(WEEKDAY,Dt), IsPromo) as AVG_WeekDay
    From [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy])

select * into #temp_table from cte
```

Edit

If you want to output the records that were updated into a temp table then you need to create a temp table and add an output clause to the update statement.

```
create #temp_table
(
...
)

with cte as (
Select *,datePart(WEEKDAY,Dt) as WeekDay,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleCount) Over (partition by ItemRelation,
DocumentNum, DocumentYear) as PERCENTILE,
avg(SaleCount) over (Partition by ItemRelation, 
DocumentNum, DocumentYear,datePart(WEEKDAY,Dt), IsPromo) as AVG_WeekDay
From [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy])
Update a 
Set SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
output inserted.* into #temp_table
From CTE
join [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy] a 
  on a.Dt = cte.dt
 and a.ItemRelation=cte.ItemRelation 
 and a.DocumentNum = cte.DocumentNum 
 and a.DocumentYear = cte.DocumentYear 
 and a.ispromo = cte.ispromo
Where CTE.PERCENTILE < CTE.SaleCount
and datePart(WEEKDAY,CTE.Dt) < 5
and CTE.ispromo = 0
```

Comment: tell where this part , it is needed Set SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
From CTE
join ....
  on a.Dt = cte.dt
 and a.ItemRelation=cte.ItemRelation 
 and a.DocumentNum = cte.DocumentNum 
 and a.DocumentYear = cte.DocumentYear 
 and a.ispromo = cte.ispromo
Where CTE.PERCENTILE < CTE.SaleCount
and datePart(WEEKDAY,CTE.Dt) < 5
and CTE.ispromo = 0 ;

Comment: can you join this part to #temp_table

Comment: the question in that, i edited my post, please check

Comment: If you want to update based on the temp table                                                    Update a 
Set SaleCount = cte.AVG_WeekDay
From #temp_table

Comment: i did #edit2, please check what i errors got. What did i wrong?

Comment: Do you want the output of the CTE in a temp table or do you want the output of the update statement in a temp table?

Comment: Ian-Fogelman,i want the output of the update statement in a temp table?

Comment: last question before accept. what argument must in this construction create #temp_table
(
...
)

Comment: The update statement will output all fields that were changed in this case alias A, so the temp table should match the table structure of [Action].[dbo].[promo_data_copy], you can R-Click -> Create to in SSMS to generate the data types for the create script then rename the table name to #temp_table.

Comment: Ian-Fogelman , please forgive me, I confused. I need the output of the CTE in a temp table. Please can fix you code. I am real sorry

Comment: Ian-Fogelman,please don't delete the output of the update statement in a temp table. Let there are be two solution. Please edit post with second solution - the output of the update statement in a temp table